# Sending binary data from Qt to AngularJs over HTTP

Tags: c++, angularjs, qt, http

```
QString path = "my.file";
//QString zipcmd = QString("tar -czf %1.tar.gz %1").arg(path);
//int err = system(zipcmd.toUtf8().data());
// path += ".tar.gz";
QFile file(path);
if (!err && QFile::exists(path) && file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
  body = file.readAll();
  file.close();
  status = QHttpResponse::STATUS_ACCEPTED;
}
```

And there how I process response:

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'myurl', respponseType: 'blob' })
              .then(function success(response) {
              var blob = new Blob([response.data],{type: 'application/octet-stream', charset: 'charset=utf-8'});
              var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              var a = document.createElement('a');
              a.download = "myfilename";
              a.href = url;
              a.click();
            });
```

When I send simple text file every thing is OK.
But when I try to send same file packed to tar.gz I receive incorrect data. I have tried to use `toBase64` and `atob`, change `respponseType` to `arraybuffer` and MIME type without any success.

AngularJS 1.4.9 and Qt 5.4. Any help would be appreciated. 
Maybe there is another way to transfer files?

Comment: Make sure you have the same correct Content-Type and Content-Encoding (e.g. Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Content-Encoding: gzip) https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2006/08/21/content-encoding-content-type/ and https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html